# Java8 style for comparing arrays? (Streams and Math3)

Tags: java-8, apache-commons

I'm just beginning to learn Java8 streams and [Apache commons Math3](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/index.html) at the same time, and looking for missed opportunities to simplify my solution for comparing instances for equality.  Consider this Math3 `RealVector`:

```
RealVector testArrayRealVector =
        new ArrayRealVector(new double [] {1d, 2d, 3d});
```

and consider this member variable containing boxed doubles, plus this copy of it as an array list collection:

```
private final Double [] m_ADoubleArray = {13d, 14d, 15d};
private final Collection<Double> m_CollectionArrayList =
        new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(m_ADoubleArray));
```

Here is my best shot at comparing these in a functional style in a JUnit class ([full gist here](https://gist.github.com/rebcabin/fbe9a9289dc9bae750d1)), using [protonpack from codepoetix](https://github.com/poetix/protonpack) because I couldn't find `zip` in the Streams library.  This looks really baroque to my eyes and I wonder whether I've missed ways to make this shorter, faster, simpler, better because I'm just beginning to learn this stuff and don't know much.

```
// Make a stream out of the RealVector:
DoubleStream testArrayRealVectorStream =
        Arrays.stream(testArrayRealVector.toArray());

// Check the type of that Stream
assertTrue("java.util.stream.DoublePipeline$Head" ==
        testArrayRealVectorStream.getClass().getTypeName());

// Use up the stream:
assertEquals(3, testArrayRealVectorStream.count());

// Old one is used up; make another:
testArrayRealVectorStream = Arrays.stream(testArrayRealVector.toArray());

// Make a new stream from the member-var arrayList;
// do arithmetic on the copy, leaving the original unmodified:
Stream<Double> collectionStream = getFreshMemberVarStream();

// Use up the stream:
assertEquals(3, collectionStream.count());

// Stream is now used up; make new one:
collectionStream = getFreshMemberVarStream();

// Doesn't seem to be any way to use zip on the real array vector
// without boxing it.
Stream<Double> arrayRealVectorStreamBoxed = 
    testArrayRealVectorStream.boxed();

assertTrue(zip(
        collectionStream,
        arrayRealVectorStreamBoxed,
        (l, r) -> Math.abs(l - r) < DELTA)
        .reduce(true, (a, b) -> a && b));
```

where

```
private Stream<Double> getFreshMemberVarStream() {
    return m_CollectionArrayList
            .stream()
            .map(x -> x - 12.0);
}
```

[Again, here is a gist of my entire JUnit test class](https://gist.github.com/rebcabin/fbe9a9289dc9bae750d1).

Comment: Whats the problem with just using [`Assert.assertArrayEquals\(double[] expecteds, double[] actuals, double delta)`](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assert.html) on the primitive doubles? I'm not sure I understand the benefit of using `Stream` here. I had to read through your code several times to try and understand what you were trying to do.

Comment: @mkobit: as far as I can see, there is no method for comparing `double[]` with `Double[]` (array of boxed values). Further, there seems to be the wish to apply a function to every element before comparing…

Comment: It's unclear what are you trying to achieve by comparing the class name with `"java.util.stream.DoublePipeline$Head"`. It's never specified that this name will not change in future Java versions.

Comment: @mkobit, Holger is right -- I want to be able to do arbitrary work on the Math3 arrays and the regular arrays with the Streams API: mapping, filtering, grouping, sorting, joining, etc.  Also, w.r.t. `asserArrayEquals`, I couldn't get it to work ... The closest I could come was `assertArrayEquals(
                ArrayUtils.toPrimitive((Double[]) getFreshMemberVarStream().toArray()),
                testArrayRealVector.toArray(), 
                DELTA);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are trying to bail in `Stream`s at all cost.

If I understand you correctly, you have

```
double[] array1=testArrayRealVector.toArray();
Double[] m_ADoubleArray = {13d, 14d, 15d};
```

as starting point. Then, the first thing you can do is to verify the lengths of these arrays:

```
assertTrue(array1.length==m_ADoubleArray.length);
assertEquals(3, array1.length);
```

There is no point in wrapping the arrays into a stream and calling `count()` and, of course, even less in wrapping an array into a collection to call `stream().count()` on it. Note that if your starting point is a `Collection`, calling `size()` will do as well.

Given that you already verified the length, you can simply do

```
IntStream.range(0, 3).forEach(ix->assertEquals(m_ADoubleArray[ix]-12, array1[ix], DELTA));
```

to compare the elements of the arrays.

or when you want to apply arithmetic as a function:

```
// keep the size check as above as the length won’t change
IntToDoubleFunction f=ix -> m_ADoubleArray[ix]-12;
IntStream.range(0, 3).forEach(ix -> assertEquals(f.applyAsDouble(ix), array1[ix], DELTA));
```

Note that you can also just create a new array using

```
double[] array2=Arrays.stream(m_ADoubleArray).mapToDouble(d -> d-12).toArray();
```

and compare the arrays similar to above:

```
IntStream.range(0, 3).forEach(ix -> assertEquals(array1[ix], array2[ix], DELTA));
```

or just using

```
assertArrayEquals(array1, array2, DELTA);
```

as now both arrays have the same type.

Don’t think about that temporary three element array holding the intermediate result. All other attempts consume far more memory…

Comment: I think `applyToDouble` is `applyAsDouble`; otherwise this is great, task-oriented info and will really help me crack the ice on these libraries.